# How do you create a sql project from the cli using dotnet new or equivalent

Tags: .net, visual-studio, command-line-interface

There are a number of templates for creating projects using "dotnet new" listed on  [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) however SQL projects are not discussed.

Is there a way of creating one from the command line?

Thanks